# How to use the drag and drop component in ant design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, upload, drag-and-drop, antd

I copied and pasted the Dragger component from ant design and i am trying to understand how to change it to fit my code. I have an upload function, all i need the dragger component to invoke the upload function when a picture is uploaded and then paste the results below, but everything i try doesnt work.

upload function:

```
const handleImageUpload = async (files: any) => {
        try {
            const data = new FormData()
            for(let i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
            data.append('images', files[i])
            }
            const {data:images} = await axios.post('/products/upload', data, {
            headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
            })
            setAddedPhotos(prevState => [...prevState, ...images])
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
```

upload props of the dragger component:

```
const props: UploadProps = {
        name: 'file',
        action: 'http://localhost:5000/products/upload',
        multiple: true,
        onChange (info) {
            const { file } = info;
          if (file.status !== 'uploading') {
            console.log('uploading');
            handleImageUpload(file.originFileObj)
          }
          if (file.status === 'done') {
            message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
            console.log(addedPhotos)
          } else if (file.status === 'error') {
            message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
          }
        },
        onDrop(e) {
          console.log('Dropped files', e.dataTransfer.files);
        },
    };
```

The actual Tsx:

```
            <Dragger {...props}>
                <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
                <InboxOutlined />
                </p>
                <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
                <p className="ant-upload-hint">
                Support for a single or bulk upload. Strictly prohibited from uploading company data or other
                banned files.
                </p>
            </Dragger>
```

As you can see, all i want to do is invoke the handleImageUpload function whenever an image is uploaded, which in turn calls the axios function and then add those files to the addedPhotos array, but i really dont know what im doing. How do i put the route in the 'action' prop when im already putting it in the axios function, even if i add the route to the 'action' prop then it still doesnt work cause it is a protected route. i dont even know where or how to invoke the handleImageUpload function. Can someone please help me on this?